# What did I miss using the residue theorem?

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

Using the residue theorem, I want to evaluate the integral along the entire real line,

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-q^2}\cos(\sqrt{1-q^2})}\ \mathrm{d}q,
\end{equation}
I can evaluate this numerically ($\approx 4.3023-2.2343 i$) but I really want to get the solution using the residue theorem. Analytic continuation gives,
\begin{equation}
\oint_\mathcal{C} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}\cos(\sqrt{1-z^2})}\ \mathrm{d}z,
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{C}$ is a closed contour in the complex plane containing the entire real line $\Gamma$ and then some contour $\cap$ in the upper complex plane at $|z|\gg 1$ which I assume I can choose such that the  contour integral along $\cap$ vanishes.

I have fond that there are infinitely many residues at $z_n=i\sqrt{(\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi)^2-1}$ with the value,
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Res}_n= \dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{z_n}, \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{equation}
But if I calculate $2\pi i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{Res}_n\approx 4.3023$,  only the *real* part of the numeric solution is reproduced while the imaginary part vanishes.

Can you spot my mistake?

I believe the problem is about my contour around the branch points at $z=\pm 1$. The imaginary part of the integrand above is even for a contour *exactly* at the real line but odd for a contour which is shifted infinitesimally upwards (or downwards) in the imaginary direction. Maybe I need some clever contour in the complex plane to catch the imaginary part?

N.B. This is physics, so I am satisfied with truncated or approximated solutions.

Comment: How are you dealing with the branch of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ ?

Comment: it cant be true since $cos(\sqrt {1-q^2})$ isn't real for $|q|>1$

Comment: Yes, I'm suspecting one would have to generate imaginary and real parts for the integrand before coming up with an expression. What happens when $|x|>1$ when the integrand is going to be complex?

Comment: Since $\sqrt{1-z^2}=\sqrt{(1-z)(1+z)}$ i have branch points in $z=\pm 1$. We can then place the branch cut between those points in some convenient way. I see no problem in dealing with complex-valued integrals here(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this problem, I think there are two things you can do, the first is to notice that the integrand is even, and that it is only complex valued for $|x|>1$. Denote $I$ by the original integral, then we have

$$I = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\cos{(\sqrt{1-t^2}})}\, dt + 2 i \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-1}\cosh{(\sqrt{t^2-1}})}\, dt$$

You have, with a pretty loose argument, shown the real part of the integral correctly is the sum you've written, however your contour only accounts for the real part of the integral, not any imaginary contributions.

Both integrals can be attacked with a rectangular contour, avoiding the branch cut on [-1, 1]

Edit: I've drawn the contour:

[image]

Technically you would be within epsilon above the interval on the real axis, $[-1,1]$ since that is the branch cut and is not a region you can integrate through. Further, the contributions to the integral as the two semi-circles approach zero would also need to be computed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you specify your exact contour? I still do not understand why my contour does not account for the imaginary part.

Comment: If you take a rectangular contour  (I went up to $R \pm i \pi$ for the top two corners), with half of a bone contour avoiding the branch cut, it should work out to what you want. The reason yours does not work is because your description of the contour implies your integrand isn't even holomorphic in your region (because of the cut). If, however, you use a limiting argument, it should work out, and is the reason you only recover the integral from -1 to 1. It'll be worth writing out all limits and the entire contour explicitly to figure out what's happening exactly.

Comment: Ahh, I see! My integrand is not holomorphic on the real line $|z|>1$.Instead I can use that my integrand is even, and instead consider the contour $z=x+i\epsilon$ for $x\in]1;\infty[$ and let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Thank you @DaveNine.

Comment: No, you misunderstand, your integrand is not holomorphic on $[-1,1]$ because of the branch cut you've chosen. This is the entire reason why you must go around it and use a limiting argument to approach it.

Comment: But if a choose my branch cut at |z|>1, my function is not holomorphic at |z|>1, right?

Comment: First off $|z|>1$ literally describes the set of numbers that have modulus bigger than one, which is the outside of a circle of radius one. Do you mean $|Re(z)|>1$? If so, then by the choice of our branch it is. It is not holomorphic on $|Re(z)|<1$, as I've stated, because of your branch cut. I'm not sure how more straightforward I can be with that, so I've drawn the contour for you. If you want to only compute the real or imaginary part of the integral, you'd probably want to make that rectangle go all the way around, otherwise you're picking up integrals that you don't want to include.

Comment: Okay, sorry. What I ment was: Since the choice of branch cut is arbitrary, isn't it ok to choose a branch cut on $|Re(z)|>1$?. In that case the function would be holomorphic on $|Re(z)|<1$. Thanks a lot for your drawing!

Comment: It is arbitrary to a degree, it must connect branch points, There's also no branch point at infinity, so the simplest cut is the one that connects them, $[-1,1]$ on the real axis.